# Create ADF schedule running from 6:00 to 20:00

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-data-factory, azure-scheduler

I have built a package for ADF IR. Cool. Proud of it.
Now I want to schedule it for every hour between 06:00 and 20:00.
I can see no way in ADF to schedule it as such.
What I did now is schedule the package for hourly execution.
The IR is started at 06:00 and stopped at 20:00, effectively running hourly between 06:00 and 20:00.

However, in the near future I will be running other packages at night so I will be needing my runtime at night. And then it will run my package that should only run between 06:00 and 20:00.

Am I missing something in the schedule options?
How can I run my package run hourly between 06:00 and 20:00 without having to start and stop my runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF's recurrence pattern is not that robust, but you can leverage Logic Apps to manage the trigger. Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134686/can-i-trigger-my-azure-data-factory-pipeline-in-5-working-day-between-9-am-to-6/62137667#62137667) where I discussed this recently.

Comment: That actually has a view other advantages for us as wel..... Thanks for this