# Is it possible to specify a skip date/period in Data Factory schedule trigger/ tumbling window trigger?

Tags: azure-data-factory

My requirement is to skip the run of a trigger if it is the first day of the month

Similarly run a trigger if it is Monday or 1st day of the month

Can we achieve it at trigger level or we have to write custom logic (If conditon/ Case activity)  in ADF to kick it off and exit gracefully by sending an email rather than running other activities ( like precedence contraints in SSIS)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Logic Apps for this kind of operation. Its more user friendly and is separate from ADF, so you can change the trigger rules without changing the pipeline. Here is [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134686/can-i-trigger-my-azure-data-factory-pipeline-in-5-working-day-between-9-am-to-6/) where I outline this approach. You would just need to modify the date processing rules in the Logic App to match your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the first ask by playing with the schedule object . Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger#examples-of-trigger-recurrence-schedules) .
This should work .
{"weekDays":["tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday","saturday","sunday"]}

For the second part where you have the OR condition I doubt if we can implement that using one trigger  , but I think we can create two triggers like .

TRG1

```
 "schedule":{"weekDays":["monday"]}
```

TRG2

> `"schedule": {  "monthDays": [1]  }`

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I managed to handle this using a master/child pipeline stuff.

I am triggering a master pipeline every time whenever I need to run a particular schedule - I am then setting various variables like "dayOfMonth" , "hourOfDay", "dayOfWeek" etc etc and then using those variables in "If"/ "case" activities to trigger respective child pipelines using "Execute Pipeline" activities.