# Configuring Triggers in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to schedule my ADF pipelines to trigger in such a way that for the 25th-8th of every month it runs every 30 mins but on every other weekend, I want to change the frequency to every 8 hours to reduce the computation.

I tried using schedule triggers but the problem is I can't select both dates and which day of the week I want my pipeline to run. That creates an issue as to how I can add this degree of customization to the triggers.

So I'm looking for a way to figure that out.

Comment: This may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134686/can-i-trigger-my-azure-data-factory-pipeline-in-5-working-day-between-9-am-to-6/62137667#62137667

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the trigger configuration steps to run pipeline every 30 mins and between  25th – 8th every month.

Select Type as Schedule. Also select Start date, Time zone and Recurrence.
Set Recurrence to 1 month.

[image]

Now Select Advanced recurrence options. Select month days, Hours and Minutes.

[image]

[image]