# How to Configure Azure Data Factory with multiple schedules

Tags: azure-data-factory

Can someone let me know if its possible configure ADF to be triggered from multiple schedules. For example I would like to execute a pipeline on:

```
Last Month End e.g 31/05/2023
Last Quarter End e.g. 31/03/2023
Last Year End e.g. 31/12/2021
Last Month End but one e.g 30/04/2023
Last Quarter End but one e.g.30/09/2022
```

I have looked at scheduling, but I'm not sure if ADF scheduling can trigger on multiple schedules as I have described.

If it's not possible to include all of the above schedules in a single trigger, can someone let me know how I would configure a single trigger for `Last Month End but one e.g 30/04/2023`

[image]

Comment: I don't think a single trigger can do what you want. I use Logic Apps to manage complex trigger requirements, check out this question and answer for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62134686/can-i-trigger-my-azure-data-factory-pipeline-in-5-working-day-between-9-am-to-6/

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran, thanks for getting in touch. Could it not even provide the following single trigger ```Last Month End but one e.g 30/04/2023```

Comment: I'm not sure as I use Logic Apps to manage all my recurrence patterns. Also, I notice in your example that you specified an end date 1 day after the start date, which does not make sense in your scenario.

Comment: Hi @JoelCochran, thanks again for reaching out. I think you're correct as regards not being able to achieve this with ADF. I have put a question out asking for help to achieve this with Logic Apps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- You can also look at conditionals in order to achieve this requirement. The following is a demonstration for a pipeline (which will be scheduled to run every day) which executes the required pipeline on last but one day of every month.
- I have taken 2 array parameters with pre-defined last but one day of each month in the format `dd/MM`, one parameter of the leap year case and another for normal year (As last but one day for Feb in leap year would be different):

```
last_but_one_ends: ["30/01","27/02","30/03","29/04","30/05","29/06","30/07","30/08","29/09","30/10","29/11","30/12"]

last_but_one_ends_leap_yr: ["30/01","28/02","30/03","29/04","30/05","29/06","30/07","30/08","29/09","30/10","29/11","30/12"]
```

- Now, using set variable as an if condition, I check if its leap year or not (divisible by 4).

```
@if(equals(mod(int(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')),4),0),'ok',0)
```

[image]

- Now, based on the outcome of this, I have if condition activities that check the respective condition. It checks whether the current date (dd/MM format) is present in `last_but_one_ends` if its not a leap year and in `last_but_one_ends_lear_yr` if its a leap year.

[image]

- Call the required pipeline when this above condition gives true and ignore the false case. The following is an debug output for today's date.

[image]

- Schedule this pipeline to run daily. You can also schedule this pipeline to run only on the last 5 days in the schedule trigger settings as your required dates fall within this span.

[image]

- Pipeline JSON (without trigger attached):

```
{
    "name": "pipeline2",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "get day and month",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "date",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@formatDateTime(utcnow(),'dd/MM')",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "if to check leap year",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "get day and month",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "year",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@if(equals(mod(int(formatDateTime(utcNow(),'yyyy')),4),0),'ok',0)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "not leap year",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "if to check leap year",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Failed"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@contains(pipeline().parameters.last_but_one_ends,variables('date'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline1",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "pipeline1",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "leap_year",
                "type": "IfCondition",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "if to check leap year",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@contains(pipeline().parameters.last_but_one_ends_leap_yr,variables('date'))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "ifTrueActivities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Execute Pipeline2",
                            "type": "ExecutePipeline",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "pipeline": {
                                    "referenceName": "pipeline1",
                                    "type": "PipelineReference"
                                },
                                "waitOnCompletion": true
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "last_but_one_ends": {
                "type": "array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    "30/01",
                    "27/02",
                    "30/03",
                    "29/04",
                    "30/05",
                    "29/06",
                    "30/07",
                    "30/08",
                    "29/09",
                    "30/10",
                    "29/11",
                    "30/12"
                ]
            },
            "last_but_one_ends_leap_yr": {
                "type": "array",
                "defaultValue": [
                    "30/01",
                    "28/02",
                    "30/03",
                    "29/04",
                    "30/05",
                    "29/06",
                    "30/07",
                    "30/08",
                    "29/09",
                    "30/10",
                    "29/11",
                    "30/12"
                ]
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "date": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "year": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```